# Why doesn't assignment inside an if statement not happen before?

Tags: ruby

I have a piece of code that has to do something with an output from another (complex) function, but only if the result meets a condition. I thought I could make it a one-liner, but it didn't work, and I'm curious why.

When I run the following code:

```
do_something(foo) if (foo = compute_foo).present?
```

I get `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'foo' for main:Object`.
I was under the impression that the condition (thus the assignment) would be evaluated before the main command.

I tried playing with this in `irb`, and when I run the line a second time the command works... So the assignment does happen, but after the `if` statement? This got me very confused, and I was hoping for an explanation.

---

*Obviously this error could be avoided by simply not insisting in a one-liner, but that's not what I am asking.*

Comment: explanation from Matz himself: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16631#note-2

Comment: It’s due to execution / parsing order. See the docs for [modifier `if` and `unless`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi this is due to the order of execution

When the Ruby encounters this line `do_something(foo) if (foo = compute_foo).present?`, it will start evaluating it from left hand side to right hand side.

So, in this casee, the first expression it encounters is do_something(foo).
But, at this point, foo hasn't been assigned any value yet, so it raises a NameError because foo is undefined.

As Stefan mentioned, this doc will provide the clear explantion of this:

https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless.

Comment: Nitpicking: the NameError is raised because the left-hand `foo` is _marked_ as a method call during parsing because no local variable exists at that point. When evaluating the expression, `foo` _is_ assigned first but the left-hand `foo` isn't updated – it still refers to a (non-existent) method call and raises the NameError.

Comment: Just to be clear: this is due to the lexical order, not execution order